# Android diferentiation between GPS systems Navstar Glonass BeiDou

Tags: android, gps, system

How can I determine the GPS signal which GPS systems comes from?
How can I differentiate between Navstar, Glonass and BeiDou GPS systems when I received a signal?
As I known there is a way to differentiation, which based on the PRN number of GpsStatus if this value is greater or equals than 200, the GPS system is BeiDou, if this value in range 65 and 88 is it Glonass. (The Navstar PRN range is 1-32 maybe.)
What is the upper limit of BeiDou PRN range?
Is there another way to determinate which GPS system signal received?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BeiDou in its final configuration will consist of 35 satellites, 5 geostationary and 30 MEO ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beidou_Navigation_Satellite_System#Global_system_.28BeiDou_Navigation_Satellite_System_or_BeiDou-2.29)). Some practical measurements (though not on Android) are [here](https://gergely.imreh.net/blog/2014/05/navspark-beidou/), showing values in the range 201–210. I have personally seen PRN 211 reported on a co-worker's Android phone.

Apparently the PRNs start at 200 or 201, hence the upper boundary is likely to be 234 or 235. Currently only 16 satellites are up, 2 of which are not operational, hence you will never encounter most of these numbers until more satellites are launched. 201–205 seems to be the range for the geostationary satellites, thus you might not encounter any of these unless you are within their coverage range.

**Edit:** NMEA seems to have created a de-facto standard for satellite IDs, which pretty much matches what has been seen on Android. I have tried to put together a list of all ranges currently in use [here](https://github.com/mvglasow/satstat/wiki/NMEA-IDs).

Comment: Meanwhile I implemented to show BeiDou satellites in my android app. 
[Here](http://www.eklsofttrade.com/lk/android/showandroidgps.html) is the unreleased test version of this apk for a limited time.
Thank you of your explanation!